# How to get apps to scroll smoothly AND real-time? (don't drive me in the arms of Apple!)

Tags: firefox, mouse, touchpad, mac, scrolling

On my Desktop I've been using Ubuntu for about 7 years now, and I love it. I now recently installed Ubuntu on my Macbook Air alongside Mac OSX. I know my way around Ubuntu very well, but there is one simple thing that really really bothers me: the scrolling.

In Nautilus and the Software Center it works fine; it scrolls both real time and very smooth. In Firefox it scrolls in steps and it has lag. In Chromium it is real time, but in hard shocks instead of Smooth. After enabling the smooth scrolling function in Chromium it behaves like in firefox; in smooth steps and with lag. In PyCharm (I do a lot of Python development) and Filezilla it works in hard shocks again. Etc. etc.

Even though scrolling seems like such a small thing, it greatly irritates me, and drives me away from Ubuntu into the arms of the extremely smooth scrolling Apple.

So my question is; is there a way to get the various programs in Ubuntu to scroll smoothly and in real time, so without it moving in steps or shocks. I want the window to scroll exactly like my fingers do on the touchpad, not like I move it every half a second a bit further.

If I cannot resolve this issue, it is unfortunately bye bye Ubuntu on the laptop for me.. :S

All tips are welcome!

[EDIT 4 YEARS LATER]

So four years ago I finally opted to go back to my Apple laptop again. I want to give Linux on my work laptop another try though. I bought myself a [Purism Librem 13](https://puri.sm/shop/librem-13/) and after messing around with the preinstalled (Debian based) PureOS a bit I want to get back to Ubuntu. So I booted into a live version of the latest Ubuntu 18.04 daily build. It all works fine, but this scrolling issue bothers me again. Just to try it out I flashed Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 on my live USD, and in there the scrolling is a lot smoother. Does Budgie use a different touchpad driver or something? Whats the deal here, and how can I get the scrolling in Ubuntu be more like Ubuntu Budgie?

Comment: Have you tried enabling hardware acceleration if it's off and disabling it if it's on?

Comment: @Whaaaaaat - No I haven't, thanks for the idea. Would you have any tips on how to do that?

Comment: @Whaaaaaat - I'm sorry to bother you again, but since I can't find how to enable hardware acceleration, would you know how I could do this? Any tip is welcome, since this really bothers me.. :S

Comment: Oh, sorry. Go to Chrome Preferences, scroll all the way down, hit the `Advanced` button, and look for the System section. It should be there.

Comment: In Firefox, go to Options, advanced tab, general subtab.

Comment: @KazWolfe thank you for your contribution but your solution doesn't work for me. Ubuntu 16.04, Dell XPS 15 2016 edition.

Comment: @Ray This question is two years old. I'd ask a new one at this point, as tech has changed a lot.